# Product of integrable by bounded function (Daniell approach)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Define the space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ as the completion, in the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$, of the space of continuous functions with compact support
$\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$.
If $f$ is integrable and $g$ bounded integrable, it is known that $fg$ is integrable (for instance, the product is measurable and bounded by the integrable function $M|f|$, where $M>0$ is a bound for $g$). But I want to prove that using Cauchy sequences in $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$. There are Cauchy sequences $(f_n),(g_n)\subset\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$ converging in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ to $f,g$, so one could try the obvious sequence $(f_ng_n)$ and see if it converges to $fg$. However, the usual trick of adding and substracting leads me to a term $ \int|g_n-g_n||f_n|$ which I do not know how to deal with. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: What regularity does $g$ have? If $g$ isn't continuous, then typically $f_n g$ won't be continuous either.

Comment: I know. Maybe the approach I am trying is not the most appropriate. The result is true without further restrictions on $g$.

Comment: It must at least be measurable. If you don't have continuity of $g$, to get an approximating sequence to $fg$, you also need a sequence of continuous functions that approximates $g$ in an appropriate sense, so that $f_ng_n \to fg$ in $L^1$.

Comment: My fault, you are right: $g$ must be measurable. I have edited the question. But even in this case, although we have a sequence of continuous functions $(f_ng_n)$, I have some trouble checking that $\int |f_ng_n-fg|$ goes to zero: as before, there is a term $\int |f_n||g_n-g|$ that drives me mad...

Comment: To make things easier, I have relaxed the conditions on $g$ even further: $g$ bounded integrable. My actual problem is to prove the convergence of $(f_ng_n)$ to $fg$ in the $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ norm.